# Annoying right white band on iPhone/Pad

Tags: html, ios, css

The web site for [makepp](http://makepp.sf.net/) has a simple 3-pane layout with a header and a narrow navigation, which usually floats left (but can be floated right by clicking on a ↔ button in its 1st <li>, or hidden with × to accomodate narrow screens):

```
+------------------------------+
+ div id="_head"               |
+ width: 100%                  |
+-------------+----------------+
+ ul          | div id="_main" |
+ width: 10em | width: auto    |
+-------------+----------------+
+ clear: both                  |
+------------------------------+
```

This page validates (except for some playing around with schema.org).  All browsers display it correctly, except for iPhone/Pad.  There I get tiny writing and a useless white band on the right (possibly as wide as the ul???).

Now I found a few people stumbling over this iPhone-bug, with solutions like min-width 100%, which doesn't seem to work, or some apple-specific meta-headers, which is grotesque – as ridiculous as designing the web for IE6...

In an Apple store I found that safari on MacOS also suffers from this, but is nice enough to put the white band outside of the window – you have to scroll sideways to see it.  I managed to download firebug, but somehow it's not aware of this white area, which doesn't seem to belong to any DOM-part.

I since also found the same to be true of Android: if I scroll right, I get this empty area.  And (only now?) Chromium 20 does too.  This means I can debug locally, so I put a red background on each of the 4 elements in my sketch: none reached out into the white band.

But if I add `html{background-color:red;width:100%;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;}` that's the one, the band is red, the width is ignored.

So, what's the clean solution to getting this page right everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was looking in the wrong place.  The side-by-side _main and ul, which can float left or right or be closed by buttons, was hard to get right.  I somehow assumed that was the culprit.

But now I found a completely different problem:  The tabs in the header are css sprites, and iPhone/iPad have a rect clipping bug.  They get it right optically, but behind the scenes they still use the unclipped image for calculating the overall `<html>`-size.  And since my combined sprites were wider than the part that ever gets displayed flush right, there was a phantom sticking out.  I've rearranged the sprites in two rows and now it's fine!

(Webkit is one more site that requires registering for taking the time to explain their bugs – tiresome!  If anyone wants to pick this up from here, it can be reproduced by downloading and installing [makepp upto 2.0.98.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/makepp/files/2.1/snapshots/).)